# Finding $y^{\prime \prime}$ of $2x^2+3y^2=4$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> Find $y^{\prime}$ and $y^{\prime \prime}$ of $2x^2+3y^2=4$

$$y^{\prime}=\dfrac{d}{dx}(2x^2)+\dfrac{d}{dx}(3y^2)=\dfrac{d}{dx}(4)$$

$$4x+6yy^{\prime}=0$$
$$y^{\prime}=\dfrac{-2x}{3y}$$

This is how I started finding $y^{\prime\prime}$:
$$y^{\prime\prime}=\dfrac{3y \dfrac{d}{dx}(-2x) - (-2x)\dfrac{d}{dx}(3y)}{(3y^2)}$$

$$\dfrac{3y(-2)-[-2x(3y^{\prime})]}{9y^2}$$
$$\dfrac{-6y-[-6xy^{\prime}]}{9y^2}$$

This isn't right since the correct answer is $\dfrac{-6y^2+4x^2}{9y^3}$

Can you please show how to find $y^{\prime\prime}?$ Thank you.

Comment: Why isn't your work correct? Did you try plugging in $\frac{-2x}{3y}$ for $y'$? Incidentally, I think the correct answer should be $\frac{-6y^{2} - 4x^{2}}{9y^{3}}$

Comment: @AWertheim Thanks. I did plug in $\dfrac{-2x}{3y}$ for $y^{\prime}$ but now I am mostly stuck on correct arithmetic. After plugging in I got $\dfrac{-6y+6x(\dfrac{-2x}{3y})}{9y^2}$ but from here I'm a bit stuck on the algebra...can you show how to solve from here?

Comment: Certainly. I've posted an answer below. Adi Dani's answer is also nice for an alternate approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$6x \cdot \frac{-2x}{3y} = \frac{-12x^{2}}{3y} = \frac{-4x^{2}}{y}$$

Therefore, we have that

$$y'' = \frac{-6y + \frac{-4x^{2}}{y}}{9y^{2}}$$

Multiplying by $\frac{y}{y} = 1$, we find:

$$y'' = \frac{-6y^{2} - \frac{4x^{2}}{y}\cdot y}{9y^{3}} = \frac{-6y^{2}-4x^{2}}{9y^{3}}$$

Comment: @user436158 no problem, glad I could help! :)

Comment: @AWertheim I believe you have a sign wrong in your final line. IMO it should read:$$y'' = \frac{-6y^{2} - \frac{-4x^{2}}{y}\cdot y}{9y^{3}} = \frac{-6y^{2}+4x^{2}}{9y^{3}}$$

Comment: @GuyCorrigall well spotted, thanks! Fixed :)

Answer (score 3):

$$(2x^2+3y^2)'=4'$$
$$4x+6yy'=0$$
$$2x+3yy'=0$$
$$y'=-\frac{2x}{3y}$$
$$(2x+3yy')'=0'$$ 
$$2+3(y')^2+3yy''=0$$
$$y''=\frac{-2-3(y')^2}{3y}$$
$$y''=\frac{-2-3(-\frac{2x}{3y})^2}{3y}=\frac{-2+\frac{4x^2}{3y^2}}{3y}=\frac{4x^2-6y^2}{9y^3}$$

Comment: +1 interesting approach, thanks

Comment: I was going to show the same method. Best way to keep the calculation simple is to keep differentiating the implicit equation and at the end substitute for lower order derivatives

Comment: @user44197. Thanks for your considerations.

Comment: @AdiDani - dense of me, but I don't see where your line $$2+3(y')^2+3yy''=0$$ comes from.

Comment: Ahh...now I do!

Comment: @GuyCorrigall Where does that line come from? thanks

Comment: Using your method I get the wrong answer:$$y''=\frac{-2-3(y')^2}{3y}$$
$$y''=\frac{-2-3(-\(frac{2x}{3y})^2}{3y}$$
$$y''=\frac{-2-3(\frac{4x^2}{9y^2})}{3y}$$
$$y''=\frac{-2-(\frac{4x^2}{3y^2}}{3y}$$
$$y''=\frac{-6y^2-4x^2}{9y^3}$$
but the answer is $$y''=\frac{-6y^2+4x^2}{9y^3}$$
Where have I gone wrong?